# How to load Windows-1215 encoded website in android webview after editing

Tags: android, webview

I am retrieving a website from a remote location HttpHelper.getGetString(). This String is modified and then i want to display this modified String in a webview.

```
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, (displayString), 
        "text/html; Windows-1252", "Windows-1252", null);
```

I tried several options, but none is working so far. For example to reencode with this:

```
public static String recodeString (String input) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] sourceBytes = input.getBytes();
    String data = new String(sourceBytes , "Windows-1252");
    byte[] destinationBytes = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
    return new String(destinationBytes);
}
```

or

```
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, 
        new String(displayString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"), 
        "text/html; UTF-8", "UTF-8", null);
```

In the webview there are always german special chars displayed incorrect.

Anyone an idea how to reencode the string to get it correctly displayed?

I tried it with a volley-request, on which I just load the response to the Webview, but that doesn't work either.

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
   web.loadData( (response), "text/html;",null);
}
```

or

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
   web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, (response), "text/html; Windows-1252", "Windows-1252", null);
}
```

I just log the content type of the response i get UTF-8, like this:

```
Log.v(TAG,entity.getContentType().toString());
```

But the chars in the response String are encoded in Windows-1252.

Comment: How did you get the string? Are the umlauts correct there?

Comment: I don't know if this solve the problem, but there is no windows-1215, but windows-1252

Comment: Changing to Windows-1252 doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: The umlauts are correct in the original website. I get the String it via EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

Comment: `String recodeString()` But that has already a String as parameter. Now how did you get that parameter? I suggest you start with just downloadingg the html source in a String first and offer that string directly (withoutt any charset as extra parameter) to the WebView. Now does it display ok?

Comment: If I just display the data directly from the Volley-response, that does not work neither. See text above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. After getting the the response I get the ByteStream from the entity and there i can set the correct charset. I have to import Guava though.

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2'
```

Here the correct sourcecode:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
{
    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String responseStr = new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(entity.getContent() ), "Windows-1252");
    return responseStr;
}
```

Thanks for your help anyway!